# Php mail() breaks 650 char long Url

Tags: php, email

Im using the php mail function to send a link with many many paramaters. The url after being encoded can be 650 or more characters long because its holding variables to repopulate a form.

When I click on the link in my email its broken because a space has been inserted somewhere in the URL.

Heres my sendMail function:

```
    protected function sendEmail($to, $subject, $body) {
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . '\r\n';
        $headers .= 'From: Sales Order From <sales@imninjas.com>' . '\r\n';
        $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . '\r\n';

        $body = '<html><body style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">'.$body.'</body></html>';

        return mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    }
```

Heres the code I call sendMail with. Its the '$salesUrl = $this->getSalesFormUrl();' that is the 650+ character url chock full of encoded paramaters.

```
    function emailRep() {
        $params = $this->getParamaterArray();
        $shortUrl = $this->getShortUrl();
        $salesUrl = $this->getSalesFormUrl();

        $mailSubject = "Return to the sales order form for ".$params['clientName']." at ".$params['company'].".";

        $mailBody = "The following information is from an order created on, ".date("l, F j, Y \a\t g:i a").",<br/><br/>";
        $mailBody .= "Customer Contact Information:<br/>";
        $mailBody .= "Name: ".$params['clientName'] params['company']."<br/>";
        $mailBody .= "Shortened Url to Send to the Customer:<br/>";
        $mailBody .= ($shortUrl) ? "<a href='".$shortUrl."'>".$shortUrl."</a><br/><br/>" : "There was an error shortening your url.<br/><br/>";
        $mailBody .= "The URL back to the sales form: For sales rep use only, <strong>Do not give to the customer</strong>.:<br/>";
        $mailBody .= "<span style='font-style: italic;'>Some email clients add special characters to long urls. If the link does not work then copy and paste it into your browser.</span><br/>";
        $mailBody .= "<a href='".$salesUrl."'>".$salesUrl."</a><br/><br/>";

        return ($this->sendEmail($params['repEmail'], $mailSubject, $mailBody));
    }
```

And here's the URL I receive in my email, you'll notice the space '...BhsNKq Jsd_x4...' in the middle of the URL. This happens in a different place each time even if I'm sending the exact same url. To prove this I hard coded this url without a space in the emailRep method and sent it multiple times. The space moved around.

```
http://example.com/admin/index.php?fdJdj9QgFAbgXzPcNJ3AAdbxgotxdk28cNRMjPESW9yihVbKxHR_vaeU7TSZxqSfHDhPX9Jg-lPneu1H9cFHE7yJxUcdfpto_XNxtv6XHkgw_Vk7oy7aFRdnYzONPDltWxV01Zi23glqnU-z91XnpvrnpvNGSXYo4Q0t6UEKUmUp9Sh28JC7Va01Pmaibcc83M8dpCzzKYn5H_rX_BhsNKq Jsd_x4w7e4zHqputSWdc1Uwzezt2LS5xGQJHKxlF98qbzUZMhauxw_k5ebK8YPwDFr776GEb11WPzGtfhjIFE68zL9H2l3FOCFXea5qkHUmO9pCihThlegDLAHamuIeCmTiXSGv8cm_TorL-6q8NnYuvp6nEfpntthgrvx3enkhWP-FJ0P4vYYAvyJ45pbR9slaw9pbPLsnu4d9nNZSuXJZdll2WXJRc2XKYgu0zRvcwuqBSVwuzylQu4ILugxOJCciG7kF1Qx8vjZl5Y8sIqL59dRu9dfnP5yuXJ5dnl2eXJ3crLl7x8lVeoFJWKe1co_uoK_B1eXZFckV2RXaG-fHvazCuWvGKVV84u23DlzZUrVyZXZldmVyZ3K69c8so57z8
```

Here is the code I use to encode / decode the url paramaters before sending it through the email.

```
class UrlEncoder {
    function compressUrl($url) {
        return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(gzdeflate($url, 9)), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    }

    function uncompressUrl($url) {
        $startParams = strrpos($url, "?");

        if($startParams) {
            $paramaterString = substr($url, $startParams);
            $host = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, "?"));
            $uncompressedParamaters = gzinflate(base64_decode(strtr($paramaterString, '-_', '+/')));
            return $host."?".$uncompressedParamaters;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I prevent this space? I know I could shorten the URL with something like bit.ly however its an internal tool. I feel like there must be a way to stop the space from being inserted.

Comment: Have you tried using a third-party mail library, like PHPMailer? It might have already solved this issue for you.

Comment: You're probably hitting a line length limit in one or more of the mail servers on the way.  Encoding the HTML through a third-party library, like SwiftMailer the previously mentioned PHPMailer should work better for you.  Doing MIME by hand sucks.

Comment: sendmail hard-wraps lines at 990 bytes.  Keep each line of your email body below this limit.

Answer (score 2):

Who in their right mind uses a 650-character long query string?

My recommendation is to save the query-string server-side. Put it in a database with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` field, then you can get an ID for it. Then you can just send the URL as `http://example.com/?email_key=ID_GOES_HERE`, a much shorter URL. Then just look up the query string from the database.

Done.

Comment: The string is a requirement of the project. We needed a sales form that doesn't use a database that could have a URL to send to anyone that would let them access the form with everything filled out. So the client gets a bit.ly shortened URL that redirects with the GET variables POSTed so that they never see the parameters. However internally the sales person needs a url back to a different form and we don't want to shorten them.

Comment: In that case, compact the data. For instance, rather than saving item names, have a code to prepresent it (simplest is removing vowels and doubles). Convert numbers to a higher base (preferably 64, but numerically rather than using `base64-encoding`, which has the opposite effect to what you're trying to do).

Comment: Oh thank you thats a good idea! I wish I could just put this in a database like a good programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I have what you need, http://www.9lessons.info/2009/01/split-url-from-sentence-using-php.html. Create tinyurl links using API,nothing in the database :)

Answer (score -1):

Ok,I had same issue. My solution was my own link shrinking... Make new table in database with few rows, few lines of code in your old script, and new page for redirect... This is shortest explanation, if you need some help,just ask :)

EDIT:

```
    function emailRep() {
    $params = $this->getParamaterArray();
    $shortUrl = $this->getShortUrl();
    $salesUrl = $this->getSalesFormUrl();
/***********************************************************************************/   
    $arr = str_split('QWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNM123456789qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm'); // get all the characters into an array
    shuffle($arr); // randomize the array
    $arr = array_slice($arr, 0, 6); // get the first six (random) characters out
    $short = implode('', $arr); // smush them back into a string
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO shortlinks VALUES(NULL, '$salesUrl', '$short')");
/*******************************************************************************************/

    $mailSubject = "Return to the sales order form for ".$params['clientName']." at ".$params['company'].".";

    $mailBody = "The following information is from an order created on, ".date("l, F j, Y \a\t g:i a").",<br/><br/>";
    $mailBody .= "Customer Contact Information:<br/>";
    $mailBody .= "Name: ".$params['clientName'] params['company']."<br/>";
    $mailBody .= "Shortened Url to Send to the Customer:<br/>";
    $mailBody .= ($shortUrl) ? "<a href='".$shortUrl."'>".$shortUrl."</a><br/><br/>" : "There was an error shortening your url.<br/><br/>";
    $mailBody .= "The URL back to the sales form: For sales rep use only, <strong>Do not give to the customer</strong>.:<br/>";
    $mailBody .= "<span style='font-style: italic;'>Some email clients add special characters to long urls. If the link does not work then copy and paste it into your browser.</span><br/>";
    $mailBody .= "<a href='".$short."'>".$short."</a><br/><br/>"; // Rename $salesUrl to $short

    return ($this->sendEmail($params['repEmail'], $mailSubject, $mailBody));
}
```

And redirect page:

```
$token=$_GET['token']; // like http://example.com/out.php?token=ahgByT or make it cleaner with htaccess
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links WHERE short='$token'");
$arr=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
$out=$arr['long_link'];
header("Location: ".$out);
?>
```

Comment: If you have long links, best way is to short them. You can do this by writing long link in database and make some random letters as token, also in db... Then you make new php page that redirect you to your long link. Similar to tinyurl.com . This is my example [http://kratko.tk/lEDmKf](http://kratko.tk/lEDmKf).This is shorten url by my script,and my token is lEDmKf,and i'm redirected to real long link. I hope you get it

Comment: Were not using the database for this project. Unfortunately that was one of the requirements of the form. That's why all of the parameters are in the url to begin with :( Sorry I didn't mention that.

Comment: Make sense then :) This is my solution for the same issue.

Comment: well, you can use frames for shortering url with API of some shortering site to short url.